# MySQL group records by a span of 3 days considering the next month

Tags: php, mysql

I plan to use this query to group the date by 3 days. I want the daygroup field to increment continuously, but it resets every month.

```
SELECT id, floor(day(date) / 3) as daygroup, date
FROM mytable order by id, date
```

Result:

```
id | daygroup | date 
1  | 8        | 2016-05-24 00:00:00
1  | 8        | 2016-05-25 00:00:00
1  | 8        | 2016-05-26 00:00:00
1  | 9        | 2016-05-27 00:00:00
1  | 9        | 2016-05-28 00:00:00
1  | 9        | 2016-05-29 00:00:00
1  | 10       | 2016-05-30 00:00:00
1  | 10       | 2016-05-31 00:00:00
1  | 3        | 2016-07-09 00:00:00
1  | 3        | 2016-07-10 00:00:00
1  | 3        | 2016-07-11 00:00:00
```

Notice that after this record     `1  | 10       | 2016-05-31 00:00:00` the daygroup field resets to 3. I believe this is because of the MySQL Function `day()`

Do you guys have any workaround solution for this?

Comment: But is your data continuous. I mean 2016-05-31, 2016-06-01 or 2016-05-31, 2016-07-09.

Comment: @TharsanSivakumar good point. right now. it is not continuous, it skips. I can make it continuous if that helps. Let's assume that it is continuous, do you have any suggested solution for this?

Comment: I think, answer is given below , you may need to get the no of day in the year, using DAYOFTEAR function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said [here](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-day-function.php)

> MySQL DAY() returns the day of the month for a specified date.

So you should use [DAYOFYEAR(date)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofyear) instead

> Returns the day of the year for date, in the range 1 to 366.

Comment: thanks! this might help. i'll try and i might find a workaround